# How to change dateformat in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, date, datetime, vuejs3

I got the problem like this
`2022-12-06T17:00:00.000Z`

This is my code:

```
<Calendar
                inputId="range"
                v-model="collectionItems.StartOn"
                selectionMode="range"
                :manualInput="false"
                dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
              >
              </Calendar>
```

But I want like this
`2022-12-05`

Comment: What is `Calendar`? Any UI component or something home-made? Please provide more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the date format in Vuejs v3, you can use the date-fns.

```js
npm install date-fns
```

and you can format date like bellow

```js
var formatedDate = format(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

If you want to working code, I made it available on my codepen: https://codepen.io/maymeow/pen/xxzmgKJ

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to format your `collectionItems.StartOn` before applying it to your custom component `Calendar`

Doest it come from your backend?

Either you parse it on your backend before sending it to your frontend, or you parse it via a JS date library like **date-fns**, **dayjs** or **moment**;

Install via yarn or npm and just follow the documentation ;)